# Dois-je ou non traduire "eigenray" en "rayon propre" ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, allemand, science

Dans un document scientifique, j'utilise le terme anglais *eigenray*, qui est un terme technique connu, mais qui n'a pas d'équivalent en français, ou en tout cas non trouvé dans la maigre documentation disponible en français.

Dois-je ou non le traduire en *rayon propre*, traduction libre mais valide, *eigen* signifiant *propre*, et en prenant exemple sur le vocabulaire mathématique où le terme anglais *eigenvalue* est usuellement traduit par *valeur propre* ?

Comment: Pense à marquer ta question 'answered' ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En mathématiques, la traduction de *ray* est *demi-droite*, comme indiqué [ici](http://www.lyceedadultes.fr/sitepedagogique/documents/math/autres_documents/cours_traduction_anglais_termes_mathematiques.pdf).
La traduction correcte serait **demi-droite propre**. J'ai aussi croisé le terme **[vecteur propre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vecteur_propre)**, mais je ne sais pas si il correspond à *ray*.

On peut aussi voir ta question d'une deuxième façon : "Dois-je traduire ?".
Il est intéressant de noter que même en anglais, le mot est à moitié allemand : en effet, *eigen* signifie propre dans cette langue. Vu que je n'ai trouvé qu'une occurrence de l'expression exacte "demi-droite propre" sur Google, et que ton domaine à l'air encore peu développé en France, il est **peut-être possible de laisser le terme anglais/allemand.**

Comment: La notion de vecteur propre est utilisé en mathématique... Je ne sais plus à quoi ça sert, mais je crois savoir qu'en diagonalisant une matrice, on obtient les vecteurs propre dans la matrice de passage... Il me semble que ce sont des vecteurs orthogonaux entre-eux qui permettent de définir l'espace dans lequel ils se trouve (tout vecteur est une combinaison linéaire des vecteurs propres).

Comment: "Demi-droite propre" me paraît une très bonne traduction. Le mot n'est pas non plus forcément très courant en anglais, *eigenvector* ou *eigenspace* sont des concepts liés qui sont plus courants. Si le passage à traduire comprend une définition du terme je pense qu'il est parfaitement légitime de traduire *eigenray*. Sinon c'est un peu borderline.

Comment: @Random: Oui eigenvalues et eigenvectors sont communs, mais j'ai beaucoup de mal à trouver des articles/cours français où on emploie eigenray ou une traduction. Je suis assez d'accord avec Nathan sur le fait de garder le terme Anglais/Allemand dans ce cas !

Answer (score 1):

vecteur propre = eigenvector. Ce n'est pas la même chose qu'une demi-droite (la demi-droite est infinie alors que la magnitude du vecteur est définie). Donc il ne faut surtout pas traduire eigenray par vecteur propre. Le problème de l'utilisation du terme "rayon" est l'ambiguïté de la traduction. Rayon = ray (une demi-droite), mais aussi rayon = radius (un segment de droite). Même si rayon sera sans doute compris dans le bon sens du terme si l'on traduit par **rayon propre**, **demi-droite propre** me semble plus clair. A noter que c'est une notion déjà rare en anglais (vecteur propre est beaucoup plus commun), donc il n'est pas étonnant de ne pas en trouver la trace en français.